# set column value as today's date based on another column value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, splistitem

Can someone help me with the below case?

I have a list with two columns, Status column with values "resolved and "work in progress" and Resolved Date column.

Here is the condition, if Status = "Resolved" i want to set the Resolved Date column value as today's date on submit.

Comment: Please mention your efforts that you have done for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Javascript on the page and modify the PreSaveAction() functionality. In preSaveAction functionality check in if condition the value of Status Field, If its resolved, set Date column to Today. I can write the script but you will get it easily if you do some googling.